# How to display login user name on top right side of the mobile screen on header div?

Tags: html

This HTML is for the home button on Register header div on the left side.

So how do I insert login user name on header div on the right side?
suppose the var user is the username variable.

Now what to do?

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left" id="register">Home</a>
        <h1>Register</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why is it tagged javascript, jQuery? What have you tried so far? You question seems incomplete.

Comment: Well as adriano66 stated, what you give us to work with here is very minimal.. I'm assuming your login works via php and you're using some kind of session. So you could save and output it from your session for example.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that every thing is done in IBM WORKLIGHT.So whenever I insert a simple text not variable for testing either it is show top of header text (here Register) or  below of header by h1,p tags but cannot keep the text right side.

Comment: This is not related to Worklight. Worklight does not maddle with your HTML. Write a proper question and provide proper code.

Comment: Just I want to know how to do this,took a screenshot and marked what I want.  link:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15844249/stackoverflow/Untitled.jpg, whether it requires session or not I dont know,how to implement session dont know,how to implement the username on the right side of the header I dont know.So please help.Thank You.

Comment: I am a beginner so I may have misconceptions sorry for that.